# Scala: Redis client implementation with Akka futures

Tags: scala, redis, akka, future

I'm looking for Redis client implementation for Scala. The client should be async and non-blocking, using Akka futures.
What I found more or less useful:

1. https://github.com/derekjw/fyrie-redis
2. https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis

But both of them have their issues. First one uses old version of Akka, which causes compilation issues, second one uses scala.actors.Futures.future instead of Akka futures. 
I saw a conversation, which took place few months ago: groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/akka-user/EDKA2aTigho/_wWcNIz2O3wJ

But I failed to find any solution. 
Anyone had something similar?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are a few new Scala Redis libraries that are Reactive (async + non-blocking):
https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis-nb
https://github.com/etaty/rediscala
https://github.com/Livestream/scredis

Comment: I use rediscala for hibernate-redis 2nd cache provider

Answer (score 2):

[scala-redis](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis) is currently the best option. While it is a blocking client, some examples of asynchronous patterns are [given in the README file](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis#implementing-asynchronous-patterns-using-pooling-and-futures). Also note that the library itself does not use `scala.actors.Futures.future`; only demo code in the spec (test code) and README does.

If you only need to store a few things in Redis, it's also possible to [roll your own Redis client with a Spray.io `IOBridge`](http://rajivkurian.github.com/blog/2012/12/25/a-simple-redis-client-using-spray-io-actors-futures-and-promises/).

On a sidenote: [Akka futures are already in Scala 2.10.0](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html) and `scala.actors` [is deprecated as of Scala 2.11.0](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html). I'm not sure why scala-redis is using `scala.actors` even though it depends on Akka and Scala 2.10.0.

Answer (score 1):

There's a non-blocking client that returns Futures available as the finagle-redis module.
Example usage here:
https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/master/finagle-example/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/example/redis/RedisClient.scala

A caveat: it currently returns Twitter Futures.  You can use that to complete the Promise for an Akka Future; an example of that is on the first code example in the slides for Blake's NEScala talk: http://nescala.org/#t-8378162

People at Twitter say they'll have Twitter futures implement the 2.10 Future trait for API compatibility, when they move to 2.10.

The author of scala-redis sounded interested in porting it to use spray-io, in which case it would be non-blocking.

Comment: Quite interesting. I was [evaluating using Redis from Scala](http://keithkim.org/blog/redis-clients-for-scala/) and found high memory consumption using Akka Futures and/or Akka IO.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [scredis](https://github.com/Livestream/scredis) which is a complete, non-blocking and blazing fast Scala Redis client built on top of Akka IO. It is extensively used in production at Livestream.